# Combinatorics problem: $n$ people line up to $m$ clubs

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, balls-in-bins

Assume that there are $n$ people line up to get into $m$ different clubs. How many ways to do it if each people is different and order of people in the line matters.

Sol. Clearly, each people has $m$ different choices for clubs. So there are $m^n$ ways of choosing clubs. Now we count number of different lines.
Let $x_i$ be the number of people lining to get to the club $i$, $1 \leq i \leq m$, $x_i \geq 0$.

Then $$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_m = n$$ with $x_i$ non-negative integers.
So there are ${m+n-1}\choose{n-1}$ ways, ignore order in each line. So there are ${m+n-1}\choose{n-1}$$ x_1!x_2!...x_n!$ possible lines.

The answer is weird since it is in $x_1, ...,x_n$ terms, and I think it is wrong. However, I am not sure how to fix it.

Any help please ?

Comment: Can some of the clubs have no members?

Comment: @user84413 $x_i\geq0$ so yes.

Comment: @user84413 I was quoting the problem, it says that in the $5$th line :)

Comment: @Jam You're right, the part after "Sol." does indicate this (but the statement of the problem itself doesn't make this clear).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there are $n!$ ways to order all people. For each of these ways, there are ${m+n-1 \choose n-1}$ ways to break up that ordering into $m$ clubs (using stars and bars), thus there is a total of $n!{m+n-1 \choose n-1}$ ways.

Comment: Arr, you beat me to it by a minute! At least we come to the same conclusion, so have an upvote! :) Btw, note that the result can be simplified using Pochhammer symbols.

Comment: @Lovsovs Sorry! The same thing happens to me frequently as well. Thanks for the vote!